# Merge or join surfaces generated in sverchek . Curves made by Bezier

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv, node-editor, add-on

Initially I created bezier lines in Blender. Then applyied Sverchok.  Visually I devided a shoe into some areas(6-7)  and according to these areas I generated surfaces through Sverchok. Now the problem is - how to join these surfaces together into one?  Because between generated surfaces I get some holes. So there is a way to fix it ?  to merge ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

for now it is one solution
http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverch/html/nodes/surface/blend_surface.html
but we need sewing node, that will do it between zero-space between surfaces.
https://gist.github.com/23349d01c4df05934ef8833d92d27629
try this gist as example

Comment: Ok. Thank You for the answer. But could you tell please, why I haven't  BLEND SURFACES NODE in my Sverchok?  I installed the last version

Comment: please, install side dependencies also